# What is the number of processes that the following code will create?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork

What will be the total number of processes that are spawned by the following code?

```
if(fork() && fork()){
    fork();
}

if(fork() ||fork()){
    fork();
    fork();
}
```

AND would behave as a short circuit operator, thus the second fork would only be executed for the parent and not the child. How to proceed after that?

Comment: Draw a graph, spawning with a square for each process.

Comment: We are not a quiz-site. State your problem, what you expect and why.

Comment: Note that if `fork()` returns `-1`, that's also considered true in C.

Comment: Draw a directed graph, representing the start, forks, and end as nodes, and the execution paths as weighted edges, the weight being the number of processes that follow that path. The 'start' node has a single output edge with weight 1. A 'fork' node has one or more input edges and two output edges. Set the weight of each output edge to the sum of the weights of the input edges. The 'end' node has one or more input edges. The sum of the weights of the input edges at the 'end' is the total number of processes. Subtract 1 to get the number of spawned processes (not counting the original process).

Answer (score 0):

```
We have to validate fork return values. Actually based on return only we can able to check no of process on your program.


fork Return Value :

-1                  => Failure.
0                   => Return value for child process.
Child process id    => Return value for parent process.
```